# Passing arguments in python by reference

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the code segment below,

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val


def insert(x):
    if x == None:
        x = Test(10)

obj =  None
insert(obj)
print(obj.val)
```

I was expecting the output of the print statement to be 10 but am getting `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'val'`. This is because the obj is not being modified by the function and is still *None* after the call to the insert function. As far as I knew, all objects are passed by reference in python. How can I get around this and modify the object without returning its new value?

Comment: Things don't work like that for primitive types in python. You may return `x` from `insert` function.

Comment: If you really want to mutate the parameter in insert, pass a one-item list: `def insert(x): if x[0] == None: x[0] = Test(10); obj=[None];insert(obj);print(obj[0].val)`

Comment: @AhsanulHaque could you please elaborate? I was thinking that I was passing a reference to a NoneType object and that reference was being assigned a reference to a Test Object. Then why isn't the change reflected in the original object?

Answer (score 1):

first, you must return the variable from the function insert.

Second, you have to assign the line insert(obj) to a Variable.

Val is still inside Test class.
you must Print it from inside the class.
also , obj.val is Not exists.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        print(val)



def insert(x):
    if x == None:
        x = Test(10)
    return(x)

obj =  None
Var_Ref=insert(obj)
print(Var_Ref)
```

Comment: You confuse global and static variables.

Comment: i used it to simpify the idea.